# Why Riemann zeta function is not a density function however it describe prime distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, density-function

It is well known that Riemann zeta function describe the prime distribution using many indirect methods like prime counting function and prime number theorem also  von mangoldt function and also prime counting function such that there is a clear mathematical formula for computing probability to get a prime number and there is a huge topic talk about Randomness in prime and do not forgot Random matrix  , now what i know if any function discribe distribution of such random variable this means that is a probability  density function , Now my question here why we do not saw any formula show that Riemann zeta function is a density function such that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \zeta(s)=1$  ?

Comment: The word  "distribution" doesn't automatically mean it's a density function. Why would it be? "Distribution" of primes is an idea different from the "distribution" of a random variable.

Comment: But many researchs  talk about for example " Randomness in prime" and also Random matrix is a huge topic related to prime distribution and density